# How to make a POST request in a flutter for web API

Tags: http, flutter

I try writing a common POST request method but it's getting below error

```
Future<dynamic> requestMethod() async {
  var url = "https://testurl";
  var body = json.encode({"program_id":"1211"});

  Map headers = {
    'Content-type' : 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
  };

  var response =await http.post(url, body: body, headers: headers);
  final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
  print(responseJson);
  return response;
}
```

Error

```
Unhandled exception: E/flutter (24453): type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, String>' E/flutter (24453): #0 NetworkUtil.requestMethod (package:fitnessstudio/globals.dart:76:61) E/flutter (24453): <asynchronous suspension>
```

Comment: What line of code causes the error? Can you provide a bigger part from the stack-trace? Please add the output of `flutter doctor`

Comment: Unhandled exception:
E/flutter (24453): type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, String>'
E/flutter (24453): #0      NetworkUtil.requestMethod (package:fitnessstudio/globals.dart:76:61)
E/flutter (24453): <asynchronous suspension>

Comment: this is error its reponse init error or http post error

Comment: What code line is at package:fitnessstudio/globals.dart:76:61 ?

Comment: it's my won code is written here I am solved the issue thank you very much for replay

Comment: In this case either please answer the question yourself or delete the question because in it's current state it probably won't fullfill any purpose for future visitors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**I solved the problem by using following code**

```
     Future<dynamic> post(String url,var body)async{
        return await http
            .post(Uri.encodeFull(url), body: body, headers: {"Accept":"application/json"})
            .then((http.Response response) {
    //      print(response.body);
          final int statusCode = response.statusCode;
          if (statusCode < 200 || statusCode > 400 || json == null) {
            throw new Exception("Error while fetching data");
          }
          return _decoder.convert(response.body);
        });
      }
```

Comment: I am getting response as dynamic now How to convert dynamic to Object?  ex.  I want to convert dynamic to List<Users> how to do that ?

Comment: Works like a charm!  THanks